# Electric dipole moment(EDM) underlying physics

Tags: electric-fields, dipole-moment, cpt-violation

I read in a physics today paper,

The electron can have nonvanishing EDM only if nature violates symmetry under time reversal (T) and under the combined operations of charge conjugation (C), which replaces particle by antiparticle (as we all know), and parity inversion (P).

I checked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34484/what-makes-electric-charge-special-wrt-cpt-theorem). So it will be nice if you can show me qualitatively and quantitatively about the above mentioned point.

Note: Simplicity in explanation is always nice. (I don't have much idea of these big words)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do electrons have shape?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119732/)

Comment: Hi lavkush. The question I've linked may not seem an obvious duplicate, but it's actually asking whether the electric dipole moment can be non-zero. Ignore my answer and read [Rob's answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/119802/1325) for the details.

Comment: @JohnRennie, answer seems to be complicated. But I tried to understand it. Doesn't match completely. Need more help. Either remove the flag, as nobody will answer then.